# Dynamically emit event from js in AFrame

Tags: javascript, aframe

Pretty much the title. I want to be able to call emit from a Javascript script. Here is my setup (edited for brevety):

```html
<a-video 
   animation__begin="property: scale; to: 20 20 20; dur: 200; startEvents: startplay"
   animation__rewind="property: scale; to: 1 1 1; dur: 200; startEvents: endplay"
   src="#myvid" id="avideo"
   onclick="this.emit('startplay'); playvideo('myvid');"></a-video> <!-- this.emit works, but calling the defined emit function won't work -->
<a-image src="#pause"
   onclick="pausevideo('myvid'); /*works: document.getElementById('v-cadrage').emit('endplay')*/ emit(this, 'avideo', 'endplay')"></a-image> <!-- emit() doesn't work here -->

..

<script>
    function emit(from, id, eventname) {
      document.getElementById(id).emit.bind(from)(eventname);
    }
</script>
```

The `emit` function **works** when invoked from the console. However, I cannot get it to work when called from inline javascript. If I rewrite the whole `document.getElement...` code inline, it works too. I observe the same result without the `.bind()` "hack".

Did I miss something? How can I make it work? Can you reproduce this situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click an element like this:

```
<a-box onclick="emit('something');"></a-box>
```

`emit` is being called within the current scope - which is the box. So it's kind of the same as `document.querySelector("a-box").emit('something')`.

To use your function simply change its name.

---

Btw I'd really recommend moving all logic to a [custom component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/entity-component-system.html#sidebar). It should simplify managing events (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65023192/2425787)) - to just `node.emit(event-name)`.